# downloaded file has no name and extension with firefox

Tags: firefox, download

I have that bit of code for file download .... it works fine except from firefox .. On firefox, it downloads an unknown file without the name and extension ... I don't understand what do i need to make it works on firefox as well .. hope someone can point out something to me .. Thanks ..

```
     Dim filePath As String = "\\server\downloads\" + "Myfile" + " " + loginID + ".xml"

     Dim targetFile As System.IO.FileInfo = New System.IO.FileInfo(filePath)

     If targetFile.Exists Then
         Dim objFileInfo As FileInfo

         Try

             objFileInfo = New FileInfo(filePath)
             Response.Clear()
             Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.Private)
             Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & objFileInfo.Name)
             Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", objFileInfo.Length.ToString())
             Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
             Response.WriteFile(filePath)
             Response.End()

             'show data in the gridview                        

         Catch ex As Exception
             Throw ex
         End Try
     Else
          Messagebox("Sorry no such file exists")
     End If
```

Comment: Right ........... I found out Firefox does not like spaces in the file name ... without spaces firefox does the job excetly as I should ..... Thanks guys

Comment: It doesn't like spaces because spaces are not allowed there by the spec.  If your filename has spaces in it, put quotes around the filename in the header.